# VB6 - "Time-Formatted" Datepicker passes invalid date (below 1/1/1900)

Tags: datetime, time, vb6, datepicker, datetimepicker

I have a VB6 Datepicker with the following properties:

1. Format Type - Time
2. Min Date - 1/1/1900
3. Value - 12:00:00 AM

And I initialize it like this:

```
dtpTimeVal = TimeValue("00:00:00")
```

However, when I get the date value of the time picker, it returns the value 12/30/1899.

Am I missing any properties or initialization logic here?

Comment: What do you expect? Try `Debug.Print Year(TimeValue("00:00:00")), Month(TimeValue("00:00:00")), Day(TimeValue("00:00:00"))` for explanation. More historical info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/12/9977245.aspx

Comment: @wqw thanks, that made sense. If you'd like to make that an answer, I can mark this question as closed

Answer (score 1):

there probably is some error where you set the format

the following works:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  DTPicker1.Format = dtpTime
  DTPicker1.Value = "00:00:00"
End Sub
```

if i remove the format line, then i get the same result as you do

Comment: I'm setting the format in the UI designer, it's one of the window's properties. Have you tried obtaining the year of the datepicker?